# How to make a screen like this on Blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry

Sorry for the title but I don't know how to summarize the question =/

I need to make a screen like this:

[image]

As you can see, it shows those "boxes" 
with UI elements inside each one.

Each "box" is placed inside something like cells of some kind of table.

I thought it would be a good idea to represent the "boxes" as individual screens inside a TableLayoutManager with vertical scroll, but I don't even know if that would be reliable.

Please someone tell me how to do something like that on BlackBerry
since I have no idea where to start.

I'm using the BlackBerry JRE 4.5.0

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I edit this answer just to show how good the solution provided by the user Nate was:

[image]

Comment: I guess, a good place to start would be here: https://developer.blackberry.com/java/ They have sample apps there as well. It seems like your question lacks some research (otherwise, what you have tried to accomplish this so far?)

Comment: If your app can be done in javascript, an UI like that is trivial to make with bbui.js and webworks

Comment: Is this a **table**, where there will be 1 ... N rows that each have a  title, a couple lines of text, a button, and then a footer?  Or, is there only ever going to be 2 of these title/text/button/footer boxes, as you've shown?

Comment: @Nate, I think it's going to be more of the second of what you said, but the boxes should not be limited to 2, they could increase dynamically. Could you suggest something to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's my suggestion.  If you want the possibility of making this a *table*, with the title/text/image/button/footer pattern repeating, there should be a `Manager` subclass that represents the layout for one *row*.

*As Arhimed noted, this solution assumes a relatively small number of rows (see comments below), to perform well.*

First, I created a simple class that holds the data that one row would contain:

```java
   /** The data representation of one row in our table */
   private class Data {
      public String title;
      public String footer;
      public String[] text;  // each array element is a line of text
      public Bitmap icon;

      public Data(String title, String footer, String[] text, String iconName) {
         this.title = title;
         this.footer = footer;
         this.text = text;
         this.icon = Bitmap.getBitmapResource(iconName);
      }
   }
```

Then, here is the `Manager` subclass that lays out only one row, which is the presentation of one `Data` object:

```java
   /** The UI for one row of data */
   private class RowManager extends Manager {

      private LabelField title;
      private LabelField footer;
      private BitmapField iconImage;
      private ButtonField button;
      private TextField text;
      private static final int TITLE_AND_FOOTER_HEIGHT = 32;
      private static final int TEXT_HEIGHT = 80;

      public RowManager(int index, Data content, long style) {
         super(style);

         final Font titleFont = Font.getDefault().derive(Font.PLAIN, 24);
         final Font footerFont = Font.getDefault().derive(Font.PLAIN, 20);
         final Font textFont = Font.getDefault().derive(Font.PLAIN, 16);

         title = new CustomLabelField(content.title, titleFont, 
               Color.BLACK, Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH | DrawStyle.LEFT);
         title.setPadding(6, 0, 0, 10);  // top, right, bottom, left pad
         add(title);

         iconImage = new BitmapField(content.icon);
         add(iconImage);

         button = new ButtonField("Button" + index, ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
         // the cookie helps identify which button this is (which row)
         button.setCookie(new Integer(index));
         button.setFont(textFont);
         add(button);

         text = new TextField(TextField.NON_FOCUSABLE) { 
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
               int c = g.getColor();
               g.setColor(Color.DARKRED);
               super.paint(g);
               g.setColor(c);
            }
         };
         text.setFont(textFont);
         StringBuffer textContent = new StringBuffer();         
         for (int line = 0; line < content.text.length; line++) {
            textContent.append(content.text[line] + "\n\n");   // double line-spacing
         }
         if (content.text.length > 0) {
            text.setText(textContent.toString().substring(0, textContent.toString().length() - 2));  // 2 \n chars
         }
         text.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
         add(text);

         footer = new CustomLabelField(content.footer, footerFont, 
               Color.BLACK, Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH | DrawStyle.RIGHT);
         footer.setPadding(6, 10, 0, 0);  // top, right, bottom, left pad
         add(footer);
      }

      // overridden just to change background color (OS 4.5+!)
      public void paint(Graphics graphics)
      {
         int oldBgColor = graphics.getBackgroundColor();
         graphics.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
         // make the whole field gray, first, and then fill in the blue
         graphics.clear();

         // paint just the middle section blue
         int oldColor = graphics.getColor();
         graphics.setColor(Color.LIGHTBLUE);         
         graphics.fillRect(0, TITLE_AND_FOOTER_HEIGHT, getWidth(), TEXT_HEIGHT); 

         super.paint(graphics);

         graphics.setColor(oldColor);
         graphics.setBackgroundColor(oldBgColor);
      }

      public void setChangeListener(FieldChangeListener listener) {
         // only the button field supports change listeners
         button.setChangeListener(listener);
      }

      public int getPreferredWidth() {
         return Display.getWidth();
      }

      public int getPreferredHeight() {
         return TITLE_AND_FOOTER_HEIGHT + TEXT_HEIGHT + TITLE_AND_FOOTER_HEIGHT;
      }

      protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
         int y = 0;

         layoutChild(title, width, TITLE_AND_FOOTER_HEIGHT);
         setPositionChild(title, 0, y);

         layoutChild(iconImage, 
               iconImage.getPreferredWidth(), iconImage.getPreferredHeight());
         setPositionChild(iconImage, 
               width - iconImage.getPreferredWidth() - 10, 5);
         y += TITLE_AND_FOOTER_HEIGHT;

         int buttonWidth = 88;
         layoutChild(text, width - buttonWidth - 20, TEXT_HEIGHT);
         setPositionChild(text, 0, y);

         layoutChild(button, buttonWidth, 40);
         setPositionChild(button, width - buttonWidth - 20, 
               y + (TEXT_HEIGHT - 40) / 2);

         y += TEXT_HEIGHT;

         layoutChild(footer, width, TITLE_AND_FOOTER_HEIGHT);
         setPositionChild(footer, 0, y);

         super.setExtent(width, y + TITLE_AND_FOOTER_HEIGHT);
      }
   }
```

And, here's a `Screen` class that would create some sample `Data` objects, and use the `RowManager`:

```java
public class StackScreen extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener {

   private Vector rowData;

   public StackScreen() {
      super(MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLL | MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);      

      // define the screen title
      Font titleFont = Font.getDefault().derive(Font.PLAIN, 30);
      CustomLabelField title = new CustomLabelField("Screen Title", 
            titleFont, Color.DARKRED, DrawStyle.HCENTER | Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH);        
      title.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
      add(title);

      // populate a dummy set of model data
      rowData = new Vector();      
      Data one = new Data("Title 1", "Some footer info", 
            new String[]{ "First line of text", "Second line of text" }, 
            "image1.png");
      Data two = new Data("Title 2", "Some footer info", 
            new String[]{ "First line of text", "Second line of text" }, 
            "image2.png");
      rowData.addElement(one);
      rowData.addElement(two);

      // create a UI representation of each row's data
      for (int i = 0; i < rowData.size(); i++) {
         RowManager row = new RowManager(i, (Data)rowData.elementAt(i), 0);
         row.setPadding(10, 20, 10, 20);  // top, right, bottom, left pad
         row.setChangeListener(this);
         add(row);
      }
   }

   // invoked when buttons are clicked
   public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
      Object cookie = field.getCookie();
      if (cookie instanceof Integer) {
         Integer rowIndex = (Integer) cookie;
         Dialog.alert("Button " + rowIndex + " clicked!");
      }
   }
}
```

There's one last utility UI class I used, to create colored labels:

```java
   /** A label field with custom font and color attributes */
   private class CustomLabelField extends LabelField {

      private int fontColor = Color.BLACK;

      public CustomLabelField(String text, Font f, int color, long style) {
         super(text, style);
         setFont(f);
         fontColor = color;
      }      

      public void paint(Graphics g) {
         int oldColor = g.getColor();

         g.setColor(fontColor);
         super.paint(g);

         // reset graphics context
         g.setColor(oldColor);
      }
   }
```

This is how it looks on a OS 5.0 9550.  I believe I stayed away from any APIs that wouldn't be available on OS 4.5 (`setPadding()` is *undocumented*, but usable).  Obviously, the layout is highly hardcoded.  You'll need to adjust for other devices, but I have to leave you some work :)

[image]

Comment: Many thanks @Nate! I edited the post to show a screenshot of how the app runs on a 8300 simulator =)

Comment: +1. Just don't forget this works for relatively small lists. I believe for large lists (say, 1000+ items) it (1) may eat too much RAM and (2) may become very slow (since too many fields in the field hierarcy to iterate when the UI framework handles an event).

Comment: @Arhimed, agreed, 100%.  The question said that he would probably only have 2 rows, but maybe more, so I made the assumption that the number was small.  For a large table, you'd probably need something more dynamic that only loaded the rows that were visible (and maybe a couple off-screen), releasing "old" rows as the user scrolled, or something like that.

Comment: @Lucas,  you're welcome.  I notice in your final screenshot that you don't have the icon images.  For my example, I needed to add image files named `image1.png` and `image2.png` to my project as resources.  As you can see, I used the same image for image1.png and image2.png, but you can certainly include a different image for each row.

Comment: if i need to add two buttons say - btn1 and btn2 in each row. So how i get the listener of each button ? @Nate

Comment: @Nate in protected void sublayout method , how i set the layoutChildand setPositionChild for the array of buttons ?

Comment: @Nate also how i get the name of button on fieldChanged(Field field, int context) method ?

Comment: @Signare, I'm happy to help you out, but now this is getting too complicated for this answer.  Your request is a little different than the original question, so I recommend that you post a new question, and link back to this question if you want.  My answer is already pretty long, and adding more example code to handle a different use case is a little bit much ... it's 1am my time, so I can look at it tomorrow if you post a new question.  Thanks.

Comment: @Nate i solved that problem. Thanks..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15565693/get-button-click-in-each-row-in-blackberry