# BlackBerry - How to improve this search feature over a VerticalFieldManager that holds custom managers

Tags: java, blackberry

I have a screen with a `VerticalFieldManager`
for holding a list of custom managers.

The screen also contains a EditField that 
behaves as a search field, so when the user
enters some text, my app loops over an array 
of custom managers and compares the entered text with the text from
every manager in the array.

If the text from a manager matches
the entered string, I append that custom manager to the
VerticalFieldManager.

These are the relevant parts of my **code :**

```
EditField _editField;
TempBeanPlaces [] _placesList;
VerticalFieldManager _vfmCellPlaces;
```

....

This is the constructor of **TemBeanPlaces :**

```
public TempBeanPlaces(String pPlaceName, 
    CellPlaceManager pCellPlaceManager) {
        placeName = pPlaceName;
        cellPlaceManager = pCellPlaceManager;
}
```

...

And this codes handles the **search :**

```
_editField.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {            
    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        String text = _editField.getText().toLowerCase();
        _vfmCellPlaces.deleteAll();
        for (int i = 0; i < _placesList.length; i++) {
            TempBeanPlaces tempBeanPlaces = _placesList[i];
            if(tempBeanPlaces.getPlaceName().toLowerCase().indexOf(text) != -1) {
                _vfmCellPlaces.add(tempBeanPlaces.getCellPlaceManager());
            }
        }
        updateLayout();
    }
});
```

This works ok when the array _placesList is not too large (length of 50, for example),
otherwise the app becomes too slow.

> How could I optimize my code for large amounts of custom managers?. For example, in case the
>   array contains 600 elements.

I really need to improve this feature. I just have read about the ListField in BlackBerry,
but since I have this code done, maybe I don't need to rewrite everything with ListFields.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered a similar question on BB forums here:

[How-to-improve-this-search-feature-over-a-VerticalFieldManager](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-improve-this-search-feature-over-a-VerticalFieldManager/td-p/2670883)

There are three workable options that I would consider:

1. use addAll() to add all the Managers at once thus significantly
   reducing the layout time
2. using 'paging' so you only add the first 15, and add later
   selections if the user wishes you too
3. Use ListField

The first 2 options would enable you to retain the current Manager code.

Try these options, in the order given, and let us know which works for you.

**Update**

Given that options 1 has not worked for you, and you are not allowed to do option 2, then perhaps I can suggest option 1.5.  Add only the first 25 or so, but add some scroll control that detects when you are getting near the end of your VFM and when you are within 1 screen, it adds some more.  This will cause a scrolling glitch at that point but the list will look continuous without the huge hit at the start.

I don't think anyone is going to scroll through 600 entries. If your search displays the number found, that will give your users an indication, and they will probably try a different search if the number is too large.  And because you have not added every single item, you have speeded up the process significantly.

A variation on this is to not add al the entries until the user moves focus off the EditField onto the list.

The other thing you could look at doing it having this 'search' process done in a Thread, asynchronously, and cancel it if the user updates the edit Field with some new input.

Alternatively if option 1 has NOT worked for you, can I suggest you try just adding 10 at most, and see if the glitch is still present.  If so, then I suspect there is an issue in the processing of your Fields, such as some paint loop or layout loop.  Compare this with the time taken to add 10 LabelFields.  Perhaps we can optimise the processing in your custom Managers that will overcome this.

**Further edit**

I had a random thought that perhaps restricting the height of a VFM might restrict the painting done.  Not true, I've tested and the only Fields painted are those that are visible.  So the performance hit is with the layout not the paint.

Comment: thanks Peter. I'm not allowed to use paging. I've tried the addAll() method with an array of Manager but the performance has not increased substantially. Now I will try the ListField option.

Comment: Thanks again Peter!. I saw later your last suggestion, and ended up using the third option: ListField. Now I have a class that extends ListField and implements ListFieldCallback. The constructor takes an array of the custom Manager that renders the row, so in the drawListRow method I call a method from the mentioned Manager for drawing the row. Now, instead of populating the VerticalFieldManager as before, I just add my ListField class(with the updated array of results) to it. I hope I was clear. Maybe I give a try to your updated suggestion at night just for the sake of curiosity =)

Comment: @PeterStrange, I'm having trouble understanding your comments in the last paragraph of your answer.  When you say *"VFM is very tall"*, are you referring to the *virtual extent*, which will be taller than the device screen size?  If so, I have a hard time imagining the OS actually bothers running `paint()` code on anything not within the visible screen area.  If my assumption is wrong here, then BlackBerry engineers need to be tarred and feathered.  If I'm misreading your suggestion, are you suggesting making the VFM shorter than the device screen?

Comment: @Lucas, if you are going to use the `ListFieldCallback`, and performance is an issue for you, I would probably **not** recommend simply creating `Manager` objects to delegate the work in `drawListRow()` to.  You can certainly organize your code so that there is one class that handles drawing of one list row, and that class might not be the `ListFieldCallback` itself.  But, a `Manager` is a heavyweight object, and for performance reasons, you might want to avoid it completely here.  P.S.  I know I've posted answers here where I used "your" technique, but they were for smaller lists.

Comment: @Nate:  my random though was wrong, I have tested it now.  Answer updated.  Also I am not sure about your issues with calling Manager layout and Manager paint in drawListRow().  By missing out all the focus, scrolling and other processing, I find this works OK, even for complicated Managers.  Remember the size of the List isn't the issue - only one row is painted at a time.  I just find it extremely complicated to understand and explaining it to someone who has never even written a Manager is impossible.

Comment: I totally agree that using the `Manager` is simplest.  However, this question was about *performance*, so I think it's important to note that the simplest solution isn't always the one that performs best.  The point is that `Manager` is a heavyweight object, and there's probably a penalty to using lots of them if you're not actually going to let them do their normal job.  [See this question for some more discussion of this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13669417/119114).  As I noted, I do use this approach sometimes, but not if I'm trying to optimize performance on big lists.

Comment: @Nate. I'm not sure I understand why large lists are really a issue for this approach. Memory aside, the drawListRow() method is the only method impacted by this and it is only called to paint displayed rows. So the performance hit is dependent on the number of rows displayed on the screen, not the number of rows in the list. So the hit for moving from row 7 to row 8 on a small list is the same as moving from row 1007 to 1008 in a large. At least that is my understanding. Or are you concerned about performance when touch screen scrolling, say if a user flicks a large list?

Comment: Yes, if I remember correctly, the memory footprint of instantiating many `Manager` objects was what bogged me down when I tried to do this.  It's been a while since I've seen such code run though, as it's one of those things I learned not to do (on large lists).  But, yes, I was also concerned with the performance of the drawing code while scrolling (I assume that's what the OP's problem was).  I admit that sometimes I get confused between lessons learned on iOS/Android/BB, but in general I find that scrolling doesn't always happen smoothly without taking control of how things are drawn.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code that handles search as follows:

```
_editField.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {            
    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        String text = _editField.getText().toLowerCase();

        // Delete the vertical field manager
        delete(_vfmCellPlaces);

        _vfmCellPlaces.deleteAll();
        for (int i = 0; i < _placesList.length; i++) {
            TempBeanPlaces tempBeanPlaces = _placesList[i];
            if(tempBeanPlaces.getPlaceName().toLowerCase().indexOf(text) != -1) {
                _vfmCellPlaces.add(tempBeanPlaces.getCellPlaceManager());
            }
        }

        // Add the vertical field manager
        add(_vfmCellPlaces);
    }
});
```

### Explanation:

Every `add()` and `delete()` method, when called on a manager that is currently displayed results in a call to update layout. So if you are adding 50 managers one by one, you will end up calling their `sublayout()` method 1+2+3+...+50 times which is 50x49/2 which is 1225 times.

If you add 600 managers one by one, you end up calling the `sublayout()` 179700 times which will probably make your phone crawl.

Moreover, there is no need to call the `updateLayout()` explicitly in this case. It only needs to be used when the contents of a field change without the knowledge of its manager.